# Dynamically positioning the table and bar chart generated using jfree chart

Tags: itext, jfreechart

Hi All Iam using itextpdf-5.1.0.jar, displaying Table(the values in this table are fetched from the database based on start date and end date in the input screen) and bar chart for the values in the above table.

The problem is I want to position the bar chart below the table, values that iam fetching from the database may vary depending upon start date and end date, now Iam positioning table and bar chart by giving some static values(234,567) , if there are large no of values table values and bar chart are getting overrided. Is there any other way to position table and bar chart dynamically.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE, 10, 10, 10, 10);
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Batch Report:", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10, Font.BOLD, new CMYKColor(255, 255, 255, 255))));
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
paragraph1.setSpacingBefore(4);
document.add(paragraph1);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
PdfPCell c1;

for (BoardBean bean : listHeader) {
addColumn(bean.getID(),c1,table,myColor,btableheadercolor);   
}
```

Add Column values to table

```
private void addColumn(String text,PdfPCell c1,PdfPTable dataTable,BaseColor   myColor,BaseColor btablecolumncolor) {
  try {
  final Font tabletdcolor = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
  c1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text, tabletdcolor));
  cellStyle(c1, myColor, btablecolumncolor);
  dataTable.addCell(c1);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Generating bar chart

```
JFreeChart reportBarChart = genBatchReportBarChart(listHeader);
PdfTemplate reportTemplate = contentByte.createTemplate(280, 230);
        Graphics2D reportGraphics = reportTemplate.createGraphics(280, 230, new DefaultFontMapper());
Rectangle2D reportRectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 280, 230);
reportBarChart.draw(reportGraphics, reportRectangle);
reportGraphics.dispose();
contentByte.addTemplate(reportTemplate, 10, height+150);
```

Now in the above code iam fixing the position of bar chart and if the values are low in number its good but if they are large in number bar chart is overriding the table values.Depending upon the table values the bar chart need to be aligned how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask the table for its total height after you've added the table to the document, and use that table height to decide where to put the chart.

Or (even easier to achieve): you can wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(reportTemplate);
```

Add that image with `document.add()` right after you've added the table (assuming that you're adding the table with `document.add()`).

Comment: Hi bruno thanks for u answer its working , I have another problem can we have two images side by side using document.add() .

Comment: You can combine the two images inside one table (one cell for each image), or you can wrap the images inside a Chunk: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=54